# C++ Libraries similar to C#?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm coming to C++ from a .Net background.  Knowing how to use the Standard C++ Libraries, and all the syntax, I've never ventured further.  Now I'm looking learning a bit more, such as what libraries are commonly used? I want to start getting into Threading but have no idea to start.  Is there a library (similar to how .net has System.Threading) out there that will make it a bit easier? I'm specifically looking to do Linux based network programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For C++, [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) is your everything. [Threading](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/thread.html) and [networking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) are among the things it offers. But there's much more:

- Smart pointers
- Useful containers not found in the STL, such as fixed-size arrays and hashtables
- Closures
- Date/time classes
- A foreach construct
- Min/max functions
- Command line option parsing
- Regular expressions

Answer (score 7):

As the others have said, [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) is great. It implements the [C++ Technical Report 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_Report_1) in addition to tons of other stuff, including some mind-blowing [template metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming) tricks.

For other cross-platform features not provided by Boost, I've had very good luck with a library called [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/). I've worked on commercial projects that incorporated its simple HTTP server, for instance, and it treated us quite well.

Comment: +1 because Poco is really nice and it is tiresome that Boost is the default SO answer to every C++ question.

Answer (score 3):

lots of boost suggestions, but Qt is another good option. It's got great support for [threading](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/threads.html) and [networking](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/3.2/io.html) along with pretty much everything else.

http://qt.nokia.com/products

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking into network programming and are not interested into GUI, I suggest Boost libraries: in particular, [Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard multithreading library, but the [boost](http://www.boost.org) library includes a platform-independent multithreading abstraction that works very well.